# Как блоку попасть в экран по всей его высоте?

Tags: прокрутка, блок

Добрый день! Прошу, объясните мне пожалуйста, следующее. Есть страница. При скроллинге страницы опускаемся вниз. В теле страницы по ходу ее просмотра имеется блок (слайдер) высотой 100%. Так вот собственно сам вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке страницы это блок высотой 100% приходился ровно по высоте экрана, т.е. чтобы при прокрутки страницы вниз, он четко "попадал" в экран. Как на примере http://tass.ru/spec/crimea-energy - там как ни крути страницу, слайдер четко становится по высоте экрана.
Прошу прощения за каламбур. Надеюсь, объяснил доступно, по крайней мере, старался. Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS-решения на существующих сайтах вы можете легко смотреть через веб-инспектор. Кликаете на интересующем вас элементе правой кнопкой мыши, и выбираете "Проинспектировать элемент" или "Просмотреть код элемента". Откроется веб-инспектор, в котором вы увидите верстку и стили элемента. В частности, для секций из вашего вопроса, стили будут такими:

```
#arctic section.full-img-text-align {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Значение свойства `100vh` дословно значит "100% от высоты экрана". Оно и решает задачу.

Comment: Сможете поделиться своим кодом? на http://jsfiddle.net, например

Comment: Вот и покажите этот код. Я уверен, 100vh работает, но у вас нет, значит у вас что-то не так, и было бы здорово увидеть, что именно.

Comment: Интересно, а что у вас за браузер? У меня как раз все работает, `100vh` делает ровно то, что и должно. Google Chrome 52. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units сообщает, что с `vh` проблемы, разве что, в Safari на iOS 7

Answer (score 2):

Вам поможет jquery. Используйте конструкцию:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var winHeightPX += "px";
    $(".you_div").css("height", winHeightPX);
}
```

Где `.you_div` класс нужного вам блока.

Comment: Нужно смотреть вашу верстку и какие скрипты подключены